# SQL query from a tutorial table using HAVING

Tags: sql

I have a tutorial I've been solving slowly and need help with this because HAVING is not one of my strongest suits.

This is the site:

[Tutorial](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_nobel_table_can_be_used_to_practice_more_SUM_and_COUNT_functions.).

The problem is 9th question:

> Show the years in which three prizes were given for Physics.

```
Table: nobel(yr, subject, winner)
```

Can you tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Please post the relevant code here in case the link is broken. And as @arserbin3 mentions, what have you already tried?

Comment: All relevant information needs to be contained in your question here, in case the off-site location is unavailable for some reason. Please [edit] to include it, as well as your effort to solve this yourself that isn't working for you. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not noticing this, I stopped the loading of a page after I realized that there is no query code but it was already too late. Number 2 answer is correct. For future references: add ?answer=1 to see the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put think you should count winners in the query, like this:

```
SELECT yr
FROM nobel
WHERE subject = 'Physics'
GROUP BY yr
HAVING count(winner) = 3
```

Remember to use having with an aggregate function (sum, avg, count etc.)
The order in which you write where, group by and having is important.

If you have problems with other tutorials, ask here.

Comment: This one is correct as the page also. But all 3 are correct. So, no hard feelings, guys????

Comment: Look at [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-select-count-and-select-countany-non-null-col) about count(*) and count(column_or_expression). In this example, there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

This will give you only rows where the subject is Physics. Then they are grouped by the year, having a count equal to three in that year.

```
SELECT yr FROM nobel
WHERE subject = 'Physics'
GROUP BY yr HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

The `HAVING` keyword is fairly clearly [explained here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp). It essentially can be looked at as the `WHERE` clause of a `GROUP BY`. If that helps you conceptually understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - first pick all records where subject is physics, then group your results by year (this allows you to count them all). In the end you can check the count of them all with having clause.

```
select yr from nobel where subject="Physics" group by yr having count(yr)=3
```